# How to display checkboxes options at multiple columns in contact form 7?

Tags: checkbox, contact-form-7

I have a checkbox with 30 options, and I want to show them in 3 responsive columns. How can I do this with Contact Form 7?

[Three Column Checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJehL.jpg)I'm expectig the first, but i'm getting the second image.
[The inline checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhDlO.jpg)